# Как задать точку вращения фигуры ? (JavaFX, анимация)

Tags: javafx, анимация

Нужно сделать анимацию вращение в JavaFX.  Использую класс RotateTransition, но там по умолчанию вращение вокруг центра фигуры. Как задать точку вращения (2D)?

Comment: Примите, пожалуйста, ответ, если он вам помог.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так.

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class RotateLineAboutEnd extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Line line = new Line(200, 200, 200, 350);
        Pane pane = new Pane(line);
        Rotate rotation = new Rotate();
        rotation.pivotXProperty().bind(line.startXProperty());
        rotation.pivotYProperty().bind(line.startYProperty());

        line.getTransforms().add(rotation);

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(rotation.angleProperty(), 0)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(rotation.angleProperty(), 360)));

        Button button = new Button("Rotate");
        button.setOnAction(evt -> timeline.play());
        button.disableProperty().bind(timeline.statusProperty().isEqualTo(Animation.Status.RUNNING));

        HBox controls = new HBox(button);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(12));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(pane, null, null, controls, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Если надо сделать именно через RotateTransition (только для JavaFX 2.2 и JavaFX 8)

```
import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class RotateTransTest1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(1, 1, 40, 40);
        rect.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        movePivot(rect, 50, 50);

        RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(4),rect);
        rt.setToAngle(720);
        rt.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        rt.setAutoReverse(true);
        rt.play();

        Group root = new Group(rect);
        Scene tScene = new Scene(root, 140, 140);
        primaryStage.setScene(tScene);


        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // Вот тут вся магия
    private void movePivot(Node node, double x, double y){
        node.getTransforms().add(new Translate(-x,-y));
        node.setTranslateX(x); node.setTranslateY(y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно сказать, что класс RotateTransition может вращать фигуры только вокруг их центра?

Comment: @EvgeniyTkachenko На самом деле нет. Обновил ответ. Просто я этот способ сам использовал.